# Gmail Clear Images When Sending Email via Mailgun

Tags: html, email, gmail, html-email, mailgun

I'm sending an email using Mailgun, the content of the email is HTML but Gmail clears images, even the `img` tag. The images are stored in a public S3, and it's accessible by the browser.

Does someone know what causes this problem?

Comment: Have you checked out [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailgun) which outlines how to Send Email via Mailgun? If not, that and/or [the Mailgun Documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/) may help answer some questions.

Comment: I have no problems using mailgun, my problem is: the gmail client do not show my image (on outlook it shows!), when I spect the html, until the `img` tags are missing, the same e-mail send as copy to a outlook works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that gmail do not accept svg images. I convert to png and all works fine.